# Code Patterns: Breaking from a do-once loop

Tags: design-patterns, pseudocode

Consider the following design pattern:

```
do {
    // Some logic here
    if (AnErrorOccurs()) {
        break;
    }
    // Some more logic here
    if (ADifferentErrorOccurs()) {
        break;
    }

    // Code completed successfully
    return someValue;
} while (false);

// Lengthy error-handling code here
return errorCode;
```

Is using a loop in this way appropriate? I simply want the functionality of the `break` statement so that I can put my error handling code in one place. A separate method would work too, true, but suppose there's a large number of variables in scope that would be unwieldy or unsafe to pass around as parameters.

Or would the `try-finally` pattern be a better way of handling this situation? Or throwing a whole bunch of custom exceptions? I'm just interested to see how others handle it in the interest of having the neatest and most maintainable code.

Comment: Are you always guaranteed to return a boolean from `AnErrorOccurs()`? If not, then try-catch

Comment: That's not a design pattern. And try-finally is also not a design pattern.

Comment: @Hosar Please explain. What would you call it?

Comment: @Extragorey It's an exception handling statement https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/exception-handling-statements

Comment: @samAlvin `do-while` is an exception handling statement? I don't follow.

Comment: @Extragorey `try-finally` is the exception handling statement.. `do-while` is a statement

Comment: @samAlvin The loop syntax is a statement, sure, but the way it's being used above to handle various error cases is a pattern, is it not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `try catch` statement instead of `do while` if you want to handle exception, since code should be able to self-document without putting comments here and there. If you want to handle exception in your code, wouldn't `try catch` statement seems more appropriate? With that said I think it is better to have the custom exceptions in the `try catch` for handling your specific exceptions.

The exception would be thrown in the method which need any specific conditions. For example, `Convert.toInt32(string s)` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx). This `Convert.toInt32(string s)` would throw either `FormatException` or `OverflowException` when the condition doesn't meet.
There is no `try catch` in that method. The `try catch` would be placed in a method which call `Convert.toInt32(string s)`.